# Django admin, how to trigger a function only once?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

I have a model let's name it A. I have registered this model with the Admin, now this model needs to have some prefilled data, which is supplied by a third party rest call, the only action an admin can do is to enable or disable something.

Now I need the filler function to be called only once, since initially the Table A won't have any data.

How can I acieve this?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR : use a management command and document the fact it must be called after installation.

Longer answer:

You *could* [use the `app.ready()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready) to test if you have any record for your model and if not call your function, **but**

1. a rest API call can easily fail (network issue or whatever) which is not something you want to happen here,
2. it might also take some time and you don't want to slow the process startup too much and
3. you might have multiple concurrent calls to `app.ready` (typically when starting your front server on a production setup) and you certainly don't want to have race conditions here.